# Remove duplicates without exact match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I need to removes duplicates from my dataframe where the respective values in columns A nd C match, and where the respective values in columns B and C match. My issue is that there are null values in column B and some of the "duplicates" aren't exact matches. Column B contains names, which for some rows just have a last and first, but for other rows have last, first, middle and degrees. Any row with a matching last and first name counts as a duplicate.

Starting dataframe:

```
d = {'A': [123498, 123498, 234875, 457898, 'SMITHJ', 'DOEJ',],
     'B': ['SIMON, PAUL JD', None,  'DOE, JANE MARY PHD', 'MERCURY, FREDRICK MS', None, 'DOE, JANE'], 
     'C': ['red', 'red', 'green', 'red', 'blue', 'green']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

      A            B                 C
0   123498   SIMON, PAUL JD         red
1   123498   None                   red
2   234875   DOE, JANE MARY PHD     green
3   457898   MERCURY, FREDRICK MS   red
4   SMITHJ   None                   blue
5   DOEJ     DOE, JANE              green
```

Final dataframe:

```
      A            B                 C
0   123498   SIMON, PAUL JD         red
3   457898   MERCURY, FREDRICK MS   red
4   SMITHJ   None                   blue
5   DOEJ     DOE, JANE              green
```

I used `df.drop_duplicate(['A', 'C'])` to remove duplicates from column A and a mask to remove the exact duplicates from column B, while keeping Null values.

Also, it doesn't matter which of the duplicate rows that I keep, so rows at index 0 and 5 could've been removed instead of the rows at index 1 and 2 and that would be acceptable.

Thank you!

Comment: Please explain the logic behind why the row at index 1 is deleted the first time, and the row at index 2 is deleted the second time (instead index 5 row).

Comment: There was no logic. Either row in either pair could be deleted and that would be acceptable. My ultimate goal is to take the count once all of the duplicate rows have been removed.

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
cond1 = ~df['C'].duplicated()
cond2 = ~df['A'].duplicated()
pat = r'(\w+,\s+\w+)(?:\s+\w+)?'
cond3 = ~df['B'].str.extract(pat, expand=False).duplicated()

cond = (cond1 | (cond2 & cond3)
```

count of rows

```
num = cond.sum()
```

num :

```
4
```

if you want filtering:

```
out = df[cond]
```

out

```
        A                     B      C
0  123498        SIMON, PAUL JD    red
2  234875    DOE, JANE MARY PHD  green
3  457898  MERCURY, FREDRICK MS    red
4  SMITHJ                  None   blue
```